# Find $c$ such that $ \frac{ n^{cn} } {n!} < 0.01$

Tags: limits

I'm trying to check a proprety of binary tree of n! items and I came upon this limit, however I'm not sure I got it right.

I wanted to know if:

$$ \frac{n^{cn}}{n!} < 0.01$$

for some constant $c>0$ and for a large enough $n$.

I was not able to show that for $c < 1$ (well, rigorously).

Thank you for you consideration!

Edit: Stirlings formula:
$$ \frac{n^{cn}}{n!} \approx \frac{n^{cn}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\  (n/e)^n} = \left[\text{if}\ c=\frac{1}{2n}\right] = (\frac{e}{n})^n \longrightarrow 0 $$
But I'm not sure if that is indeed correct

Comment: It is $\infty$ if $c \geq 1$. Use Stirling's Formula.

Comment: I am guessing that $c$ is a constant, it cannot depend on $n$, i.e., you cannot take $c=1/(2n)$.

Comment: Please don't use math-only titles. They are discouraged for particular reasons - see [Guidelines for good use of MathJax in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233).

Comment: @soupless Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the real domain (then considering $n$ as a continuous variable), consider the function
$$f(n)=\log \left(\frac{n^{c n}}{n!}\right)-\log(10^{-2})$$ Assuming $c>0$, $f(0)=1+2\log(10) >0$. The first derivative is
$$f'(n)=c(1+ \log (n))-H_n+\gamma$$ Using asymptotics
$$f'(n)=((c-1) \log (n)+c)-\frac{1}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which can cancel at
$$n_*=\frac{1}{2 (c-1)\, W\left(\frac{e^{\frac{c}{c-1}}}{2 (c-1)}\right)}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. Since the argument must be larger that $-e^{-1}$, the solution exists for $c \geq \frac 12$.

For $n > n_*$, $f(n)$ is continuously decreasing and then, there is a root for $f(n)=0$.

Using, for large values of $n$
$$f(n)\sim n ((c-1) \log (n)+1)-\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi  n)+2\log(10)$$ and making an expansion around $n_*$, we have as an *estimtae of the solution
$$n_0=n_*+\sqrt{-\frac{2 n_*^2 \left(2 (c-1) n_* \log (n_*)+2 n_*-\log \left(\frac{\pi 
   n_*}{5000}\right)\right)}{2 (c-1) n_*+1} }$$

Just a few values of $n$ such that $f(n)=0$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c & n \\
 0.90 &  22013.3 \\
 0.85 &  788.111 \\
 0.80 &  154.138 \\
 0.75 &  60.7849 \\
 0.70 &  33.8702 \\
 0.65 &  22.7305 \\
 0.60 &  16.9980 \\
 0.55 &  13.6022 \\
 0.50 &  11.3875
\end{array}
\right)$$ and, as usual, take $\lceil n \rceil$.

Trying for $c=\frac 34$,  if $$g(n)=\frac{n^{3 n/4}}{n!}-\frac{1}{100}$$ $$g(60)=0.00249198\qquad \text{while}\qquad g(61)=-0.00059551$$

The solution is easily obtained using Newton method starting iterations at $n_0$. For the worked example, the iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & n_k \\
 0 & 52.1791 \\
 1 & 61.4388 \\
 2 & 60.7879 \\
 3 & 60.7849
\end{array}
\right)$$